# IEnumerable<Entity>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' for Async Task Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to pick 1 record from a table but the error i keep getting is

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition
>   for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public class IntermediaryAssignment
    {   
       public string Company{get;set:}
       public string RegistrationNumber{get;set:}
       public bool Dispatched{get;set:}
    }

public async Task<IntermediaryAssignment> PickOneSticker(string company, 
                  string registrationNumber)
    {
        var db = new DatabaseContext();
        var results = await (from s in db.IntermediaryAssignment
                             where s.Dispatched == false && s.CompanyCode == 
                             company && s.RegistrationNumber ==
                              registrationNumber orderby s.StickerCode 
                             ascending select s).ToList().Take(1);
        return results.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: You can not await ToList method because its not async. You should use ToListAsync or remove await from result and add await to results.FirstOrDefaultAsync() which is awaitable.

Comment: You can always just use Task.Run if you want to use the async stuff, but as pointed above, its not an async method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var db = new DatabaseContext();
    var results = await (from s in db.IntermediaryAssignment
                         where s.Dispatched == false && s.CompanyCode == 
                         company && s.RegistrationNumber ==
                          registrationNumber orderby s.StickerCode 
                         ascending select s).ToListAsync());

    return results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = await (from s in db.IntermediaryAssignment
                         where s.Dispatched == false && s.CompanyCode == 
                         company && s.RegistrationNumber ==
                          registrationNumber orderby s.StickerCode 
                         ascending select s).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return results;
```

If your intention to take first item based on the order its best to use `FirstOrDefault` without `ToList()` & `Take(1)`

> `FirstOrDefault` materialize the query and bring the first item from database.
>
> `ToList()` if you need to get items based on your filter use to list.

In your current query `.ToList().Take(1);`
The `ToList()` bring all data to memory and takes the first one, instead of this you can directly fetch first item from db using `FirstOrDefault`